# setContentView выполняется около 500 мс

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-layout

Всех приветствую. Методом отладки обнаружил,что setContentView в моём приложении выполняется около 500-600 мс,из-за чего происходит фриз приложения. Подскажите пожалуйста,из-за чего это может быть (frameLayout нужен для добавления фрагрента)? Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".`ActivityDetails.java`">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/secondcontainer"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/secondcontainer"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_or_remove_post_to_favourites"
        android:text="@string/add_to_favourites"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: покажите еще и код активити / фрагмента.

Comment: @Wlad В этом,на мой взгляд,нет смысла,т.к я выяснил,что именно setContentView дольше всех выполняется,а теперь я выяснил,что именно WebView замедляет работу этого метода где-то в 10 раз.

Comment: Сначала нужно открыть макет с пустыми данными, а после в отдельном потоке получать данные и выводить их в ваши `WebView` и прочее. Иначе, да, будут фризы.

Comment: Если вы новичек, то советую сразу начать использовать ConstraintLayout и забыть навсегда о RelativeLayout. Это не решит вашу проблему, просто совет на будущее)

Answer (score 0):

Какую реализацию setContentView ты вызываешь? И в каком методе жизненного цикла? Лучше показать код, сейчас я только могу озвучить свои развёрнутые предположения.

1. Если setContentView ты передаёшь id, то проблем быть не должно. С твоим устройством что-то не так и я бы посоветовал проверить на другом.
2. Если setContentView ты передал конструктор класса фрагмента, который создаётся долго - убери тяжёлую работу из конструктора в отдельные методы, которые вызовешь потом.
3. В целом, уверен ли ты что проблема именно в setContentView, а не в, например, аттаче дебаггера? Как ты замерил время выполнения данного метода?

Жизненный цикл Android предполагает, что фоновая работа и данные отделены от UI (потому что например при повороте устройства фрагмент уничтожится), поэтому тяжёлая работа с данными и должна происходить в отдельном потоке (по умолчанию поток выполнения в Андроиде - UI поток). Отсюда также следует гипотеза, что у тебя UI поток в этот момент может выполнять какую-то другую работу, которая увеличивает время установки контента.

Comment: Как я выяснил setContentView тормозит даже с одним обычным пустым webview.

Comment: @alexandrkozlovskiy ещё раз, напиши подробнее как ты измерил время работы метода setContentView

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis

Comment: @alexandrkozlovskiy Покажи код